# Fixed blocks in simulink diagram

Tags: matlab, callback, block, simulink

Is there any solution for fixing a block in simulink diagram, to disable moving/resizing for the block ?
Is there any solution to draw kind of a shape in simulink (empty rectangles) ?
my aim is to fix an area in the model, so that the user is not allowed to design the model outside this area.
I tried using the callback functions with no success.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is just a compromise.

As mentioned in the other answer you need to create a subsystem. In the block parameters you can set `ReadOnly`, so everything is fixed and greyed out, as you desired, or `NoReadOrWrite` access, so it is completely blocked. This solution works just for "naive" users as they can still change the properties to get access again. Maybe you find a way to prevent the user from entering the properties menu.

The secure way is much more complicated: [protected Models](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/simulink/ug/protecting-referenced-models.html)

Regarding your question about the rectangular shape: I tried to find a solution for a long time and I'd say there is no way to "draw" something, though the backround is actually called "canvas" ;)

To your other comment: what is wrong about a subsystem? You can just block everything except the block you want the user to play around with. It opens in a new tab/window and it doesn't matter how big is everything. What you want is probably not possible in that manner.

Comment: Thanks for the answer thewaywewalk, i'll try in depth the subsystem approach.

Comment: This is what i'm thinking too, i need to think about it differently. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that to some extent using callback functions. For example let's have `LoadFcn` as:

```
A=get_param(gcb, 'Position');
```

and `MoveFcn` as

```
try                           
    set_param(gcb, 'Position', A);
catch                         
end
```

This will prohibit moving and resizing, but not cut or delete. Obviously, this will pollute the workspace so you need to think of a way to manage that. If you want this for many blocks you can add the position to the `userData` property of block `currBlock` by

```
set_param(currBlock, 'UserData', get_param(currBlock, 'Position'));
```

and then just add this to the block's `MoveFcn` callback

```
try                                                    
    set_param(gcb, 'Position', get_param(gcb, 'UserData'));
catch                                                  
end
```

You can even do this programmatically

```
moveFcn = sprintf([...
    'try\n' ...
    '    set_param(gcb, ''Position'', get_param(gcb, ''UserData''));\n' ...
    'catch\n' ...
    'end\n']);
set_param(currBlock, ...
    'UserData', get_param(currBlock, 'Position'), ...
    'MoveFcn', moveFcn);
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried using blocks? See this example: http://blogs.mathworks.com/seth/2008/07/27/how-to-make-your-own-simulink-block/

Comment: Thanks multipllayer, i've tried that, but the blocks are still resizable/movable, the objectif is to fix kind of a rectangle backgrounf as a surface where to design the model.